# Macro that applies border to all the excel files in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA/MACRO I am trying to create a macro that puts/applies Border to all the excel file present in a folder.

Comment: `If Not Right(FolderPath, 1)="\"` ?

Comment: Or `If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\"`.

Comment: There are also plenty of examples of how to loop through folders and open workbooks.

Comment: Ok I have changed to "If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\"" now it just execute without any output or any error there is no output

Comment: What do you expect that code to do?

Comment: Change `With xlWB.Sheets("POL") Or xlWB.Sheets("POD")` to `With xlWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange`.

Comment: Did see my edits in code in main codes... It is not working does not give any error also no output

Comment: `Set xlWb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FolderPath & StrFile)`. Get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` you presumably have, which is hiding all the errors.

Comment: Did the changes no output

Comment: `Workbooks.Close` doesn't make any sense - `xlWb.Close SaveChanges:=True`

Comment: Get rid of the `If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then` and `End If`.

Comment: Some1, please answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim StrFile As String
    
    ' Put your folder path here
    FolderPath = "C:\Temp"
    
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook, xlWS As Excel.Worksheet
    
    StrFile = Dir(FolderPath)
    
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        ' Basic check that this is a spreadsheet
        If Right(StrFile, 5) = ".xlsx" Then
            Set xlWB = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & "/" & StrFile)
            
            For Each xlWS In xlWB.Worksheets
                If xlWS.Name = "POL" Or xlWS.Name = "POD" Then
                    With xlWS.UsedRange
                        With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                            .Weight = xlThick
                        End With
                    End With
                End If
            Next
            
            xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
        End If
        
        StrFile = Dir()
    
    Loop
```

You should consider better error checking and validation that the files you are finding are in fact Excel workbooks.

Comment: now it works... much appreciate your help... thanks a lot

Comment: Excellent...I edited my answer to be more specific about only editing sheets with the names POD or POL.

Comment: Thanks actually from your first answer I removed (xlEdgeLeft) from.Border(xlEdgeLeft) because it was only highlighted that 1 line at extreme left the last column so after I removed that the module had given the desired result..